# Can any one help me regarding the conversion of Oracle Scripts to SQL Server Scripts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle10g

Is there any tool for conversion of Oracle Scripts to Sql server 2005 Scripts?If there please provide me the link.I had nearly 950 tables .Thanks in advance

Comment: Poor you, you have a lot of work to perform :-S

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the database running in Oracle, perhaps you could try using the Import features of SQL Server...see this [shortish msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx). You would just need to have the Oracle .Net data provider according to the page.

disclaimer: really, I have no idea if this would/could work...other than what I would expect that an Import tool could/should provide...

Answer (score 0):

Use  http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/Migration-oracle.aspx

Comment: Do we have any option in  Sql Server 2008?

Comment: Once you get it into SQL Server 2005 (the hard part), it should be fairly straight forward going from 2005 -> 2008.